# How to get base address of where MVC site is uploaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to know the root address of where my ASP.NET MVC WebAPI site is uploaded (to enable cross origin requests).

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("mydomain.com", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
}
```

There are suggestions to get it from the request:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

But this is not in a request, it is in app startup.

How to get host address without `www`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use a configuration file?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto do I need to specify the address in configuration file manually?

Comment: Well, yes. Otherwise, you could attempt to read the configuration from IIS